# How to set a specific device ID on OpenNIGrabber?

Tags: c++, linux-device-driver, openni, point-cloud-library, asus-xtion

how can I set a specific device ID to the constructor of the `OpenNIGrabber` object?

The tutorial example with `OpenNIGrabber("#1")` or `OpenNIGrabber("#2")` works well but I need to select a specific device somehow.
Is it possible to choose the device connected to a specific USB port?

I'm using some Xtion PRO.
I'm on ubuntu 13.04 64bit.

Comment: Hm for me it is not working also with asus xtion pro on ubuntu 14.04:                                     what():  void pcl::OpenNIGrabber::setupDevice(const string&, const pcl::OpenNIGrabber::Mode&, const pcl::OpenNIGrabber::Mode&) in /build/pcl-1.7-K_Z193/pcl-1.7-1.7.1/io/src/openni_grabber.cpp @ 373 : No matching device found                                                                                                                                             Just trying to get http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/tracking.php to run ..... What is #1 doing anyway????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `bus@address` ID where bus number and USB port address (device) can be looked up with `lsusb` command on Linux. This type of device ID works only on non-Windows systems as you can see in PCL sources (https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/master/io/src/openni_grabber.cpp#L352-L361, method `pcl::OpenNIGrabber::setupDevice`, lines 352-361).

Also you can use ASUS Xtion Pro's serial number as an ID.

More in PCL documentation: http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.7.2/a00897.html#a5753a422ff92067c9065797697d69244

### Example

```
quepas@ubuntu:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1d27:0601 ASUS 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Then:

```
OpenNIGrabber("1@2")
```